# Quick Quran verse links

Tags: script, sites, jquery

### Screenshot

[image: Easy reference to 2:255]

### About

At [Islam Stack Exchange](https://islam.stackexchange.com/) we often refer to Quran verses in answers. This script makes it easier to add those references by adding an input field directly before the question/answer field.

### Installation

[From userscripts.org](https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/source/466443.user.js)

### Code

https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/466443

### Bugs

Please report bugs here in the answers sections.

Comment: Nice freehand circles. [I'm going to have to upvote.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/223030)